# In a mapreduce job, when is data written to disk?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I know each mapper writes its intermediate data to disk, and then the reducers dump their output to disk.  Are there any other times when data could spill to disk during a mapreduce job?  I'm looking for literally any possible time even if it's not in a typical job.

Answer (score 1):

MR takes input from the HDFS, each map task process it , keeps in memory ,if exceed the default 100MB(io.sort.mb), then it split to disk.Then reducer output the result to HDFS not disk.For more details check the link,
    https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-6/shuffle-and-sort

Answer (score 1):

You can define the percentage when mapper shall spill its output as

> mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps in mapred-site.xml file.

[This](http://www.hadoopforum.org/index.php?action=viewPost&topicId=66&topicdesc=what+does+reduces+do+while+map+is+running%3F&categoryId=32&catDesc=)
might help!!